# Convert specific YAML to JSON

Tags: json, yaml, jsonparser

Let's say I have the following specific YAML file:

```
  task:
    container:
      image: ubuntu:latest
      args: tail
      args: -f
      args: /dev/null
      mounts:
        source: /home/testVolume
        target: /opt
```

using the ruby command `ruby -ryaml -rjson -e 'puts JSON.pretty_generate(YAML.load(ARGF))' test.yml > testTab.json` I get only the last args printed:

```
    "task": {
      "container": {
        "image": "ubuntu:latest",
        "args": "/dev/null",
        "mounts": {
          "source": "/home/testVolume",
          "target": "/opt"
        }
```

My question is how to get all the three args printed instead of only the last one?

Answer (score 2):

Your YAML is invalid. Quoting from the [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572):

> JSON's RFC4627 requires that mappings keys merely “SHOULD” be unique, while YAML insists they “MUST” be. Technically, YAML therefore complies with the JSON spec, choosing to treat duplicates as an error. In practice, since JSON is silent on the semantics of such duplicates, the only portable JSON files are those with unique keys, which are therefore valid YAML files.

It is an error to have multiple identical keys in a YAML mapping. However, JSON allows it since it only states that they *SHOULD* be unique. Therefore, the resulting JSON would be valid if an implementation supports it, but beware that it is not required to.

The answer to your question is: It does not work because your input is not valid YAML. Choose a structure that is representable in YAML, then it will work. For example:

```
task:
  container:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    args:
    - tail
    - -f
    - /dev/null
    mounts:
      source: /home/testVolume
      target: /opt
```

Resulting JSON:

```
{
  "task": {
    "container": {
      "image": "ubuntu:latest",
      "args": [
        "tail",
        "-f",
        "/dev/null"
      ],
      "mounts": {
        "source": "/home/testVolume",
        "target": "/opt"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue here is that this YAML file is generated automatically from some logs, so I just can't control it

Comment: Well if your YAML implementation (I don't know the Ruby one) provides an API that lets you query the parser events (rather than the resulting structure), you can skip composition and directly generate JSON. NimYAML for example is able to transform your YAML correctly because transformation works on the event level ([test it yourself](https://nimyaml.org/testing.html)). [I am the author of NimYAML]